# Why did Niko Bellic join the army?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

During the course of the game, Niko talks about his experiences in the army, but what army is he speaking of?  Why did he have to join?

Answer (score 14):

[Niko](http://gta.wikia.com/Niko_Bellic) hails from what is now Serbia, which was once part of Yugoslavia in Eastern Europe.  During the 1990s, this region was in a state of frequent turmoil and civil war.  It's heavily implied that Niko was coerced or forced into service in the army as a teen.  The experience scarred him, and he deals with the fallout from his (and his friend's/family's) actions during the war over the course of the game.

Further discussion of the [Yugoslav Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugoslav_Wars) is probably outside the scope of this site, but there's a good Wikipedia article on it.